# Show that following conditions are equivailent?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Do the following conditions are equivalent?

a) $f(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathbb{R}$

b) $f(\overline{z})=\overline{f(z)}$

Inclusion from b to a:

$f(\overline{z})=f(x-iy)=u(x,-y)+iv(x,-y)$

$\overline{f(z)}=\overline{f(x+iy)}=u(x,y)-iv(x,y)$

So when $z\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $y=0$ and thus $v(x,0)=0$ and we have our implication. Correct?

I'm thinking now about $\implies$...

Comment: No, it is not ok. The function $g$ is only defined on the reals, hence you cannot refer to theorems concerning holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$. (I.e., it does not need to be a constant).

Comment: Note in particular that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a domain in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: ohhh youre right. i forgot it completely

Comment: I edited the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument that (b) implies (a) is correct. Also, since $x = \overline{x}$ if $x$ is real, (b) implies that
$$f(x) = f(\overline{x}) = \overline{f(x)},$$
and hence $f(x)$ is real.

The converse statement is a little trickier. Since $f$ is assumed to be entire, it has an everywhere convergent Taylor series. It's enough to show that all coefficients are real.
But, this is equivalent to showing that $f^{(k)}(0)$ is real for all $k = 0,1, \dots$. Clearly, $f(0)$ is real. More importantly, since $f$ is complex differentiable it is real smooth. But the (real) derivative of a real function is real. Hence $f^{(k)}(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R$.